# Find all values in $\Bbb C$ of $sech^{-1}(i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Find all the values in $\Bbb C$ of $sech^{-1}(i)$

My solution is First recall that $sech^{-1}(z)=\log(\frac{1}{z}+\sqrt{(\frac{1}{z^2}-1)})$, Then evaluating at $z=i$ we get that $sech^{-1}(i)=\log(\frac{1}{i}+\sqrt{-2}) = \log(-i+2i)=\log(i)$ 
Now recall that $\log(i)=Log(|z|)+i(\arg(z)+2k\pi)$ where $k\in \Bbb Z$ where $\arg(z)=\theta$ and $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$ then substituting into the formula we get that $\log(i)=i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$, is this correct?, and if so when i draw an Argand diagram would it just be points on the imaginary axis at every $(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: How did you go from $\sqrt{-2}$ to $2i$? What about the negative root?

Comment: I've just realized there would be two cases one when + and one when - is my approach for the positive root correct ?

Comment: No, the square root of $2$ is not $2$ itself. Everything else has the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be looking for all values of $z$ so that
$$
\frac2{e^z+e^{-z}}=i
$$
which means
$$
e^{2z}+2ie^z+1=0\implies e^z=i\left(-1\pm\sqrt2\right)
$$
That is,
$$
z=\pm\left(\log\left(\sqrt2+1\right)+\left(2k-\frac12\right)\pi i\right)
$$

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution, however i'm unsure how you have gone from the second line to the third, could you please explain this?.

Comment: I computed $$\begin{align}\log\left(i(-1+\sqrt2)\right)&=\log(\sqrt2-1)+\left(-2k+\frac12\right)\pi i\\&=-\left(\log(\sqrt2+1)+\left(2k-\frac12\right)\pi i\right)\end{align}$$ and $$\log\left(i(-1-\sqrt2)\right)=\log(\sqrt2+1)+\left(2k-\frac12\right)\pi i$$

Comment: i understand how you got $log(\sqrt{2}-1)$ but how did you calculate $(-2k+\frac{1}{2})\pi i$ does this mean that the argument is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and if so how did you calculate this?

Comment: $\log(i)=\left(-2k+\frac12\right)\pi i$ because $e^{2\pi i}=1$.

Comment: wait i dont understand this, i thought to evaluate $\log(i(-1+\sqrt{2}))$ we use the following formula $\log(z)=Log(|z|)+i(\arg(z)+2k\pi)$ in this case $z=-i\pm i\sqrt{2}\implies |z|=-1+\sqrt{2}$ then $\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ since, there isn't a real component and the imaginary component is greater then $0$

Comment: arg is unknown up to a multiple of $2\pi$. Furthermore, the smallest arg for $-i-i\sqrt2$ is $-\frac\pi2$.

Comment: But for the first case we have that the arg of $-i+\sqrt(2)i$, i don't understand the reasoning does this mean we cannot calculate the argument of $(i(-1+\sqrt{2}))$, how did you evaluate the argument then for both cases, without using that formula to simplify the logarithm.

Comment: Note the $\pm$ in front. When using the $-$, we get the $+\frac\pi2i$. Furthermore, $\operatorname{sech}(z)$ is an even function, so if $\operatorname{sech}(z)=i$, then $\operatorname{sech}(-z)=i$.